Are there any free tools for converting images to video with prompt
I am currently thinking of is to use ControlNet with stable diffusion to generate images/pose and combine them into a video. Another solution may be generate the video using text to video first and use deepfake/ReActor to replace the character.
However, I'm open to exploring other tools or libraries that might better suit this requirement. As I want the character keep changing pose, Heygen may not work.
I have looked into basic image-to-video conversion tools, but haven't found many that explicitly support adding prompts or annotations in a flexible manner. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

I suppose what you mean by "free" here is probably "gratis"/free of charge.
There is free software and free usage/computing power. For free software, check the "Text-to-Video" tag on Huggingface. There you will find a lot of downloadable AI models with free licenses , small and big;  very recently released and older models.
However you have to set them up yourself and run them locally (or in the cloud or on a rented server). Given that any text-to-video task is very compute-intensive, that is what you need to do to keep operating costs low.
In order to learn how to set them up locally I recomment the "Open Source Models with  Huggingface course on Deeplearning.ai

Thank you for the suggestion. However, I need image to video, not text to video.

There is also an "Image-to-Video" tag  for filtering such models on Huggingface

You could try Dream Machine from Luma Labs. Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but it could be of use maybe, as it supports combining starting image/frame and prompt.
The issue is that the generated videos are short. But you could get around it by stitching few generated videos, where next generation is based on last frame from the last generated video.
